# .NET C# I want to get the IDs (1/multiple) from a data if it much the ID of another table

Tags: c#, .net, linq, repository, where-clause

Models:

```
namespace practise_API.Model
{
    public class SourceAttributes
    {
        [Key]
        public int SourceEntityId { get; set; }

        public int ATiD { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Datatype { get; set; }
    }

    public class OtherData
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Ename { get; set; }
        public string Type { get; set; }
        public string Source { get; set; }
        public string Frequency { get; set; }
    }
}
```

`IRepository` interface:

```
namespace API.Repository
{
    public interface ISourceRepository
    {
        IEnumerable<SourceEntities> GetSourceEntities();
        IEnumerable<SourceAttributes> GetSourceAttributes(int id);

        ........
        void Save();
    }
}
```

`Repository` implementation:

```
public class SourceRepository : ISourceRepository
{
    private readonly MapperDbContext _dbContext;

    public SourceRepository(MapperDbContext dbContext)
    {
        _dbContext = dbContext;
    }

    public IEnumerable<SourceAttributes> GetSourceAttributes()
    {
        return _dbContext.SourceAttributes
                         .Where(i => i.SourceEntityId == OtherData.ID)
                         .ToList();
    }
}
```

I want to get all the `SourceAttributes.SourceentityIds` that match that one ID from `OtherData`. The way I thought about it was to use where() System.Linq but I can't get the OtherData.ID.

Also this is going to be called later in my `Get()` of my controller.

Comment: @GertArnold Its just another object....Anyway the reason it was not working is simply I forgot to declare the id -> getSourceAttributes(int id)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `ISourceRepository.GetSourceAttributes` has an `id` parameter, but the implementation is missing it resulting surely in a compiler error.
Modify it:

```
public IEnumerable<SourceAttributes> GetSourceAttributes(int otherDataId)
{
   return _dbContext.SourceAttributes
      .Where(i => i.SourceEntityId == otherDataId)
      .ToList();
}
```

To get the ids you want:

```
var ids = sourceRepository
            .GetSourceAttributes(myOtherDataInstance.ID)
            .Select(i => i.ID)
            .ToArray();   // or leave it as IEnumerable as you wish
```